# JQuery UI slider : set min and max with attributes

Tags: jquery-ui, attributes, slider, this

I need to work with **several sliders** in the same page. Therefore I've created a class for the sliders (so there's only one jquery code) and I want to set the **max and min values to attributes** of the divs. They will then change according to the slider selected.

I'm guessing to do that I would need to use `this` at some point, or else it will target every class. Although I have no idea where to start or where to include it.

For now I've just applied the basic code, here it is:

**HTML :**

```
<div class="slider" slider-min="15" slider-max="250" svalue="132"></div><span class="slider-value"></span>
<div class="slider" slider-min="30" slider-max="300" svalue="165"></div><span class="slider-value"></span>
<div class="slider" slider-min="100" slider-max="500" svalue="300"></div><span class="slider-value"></span>
```

**CSS :**

```
.ui-slider { position: relative; text-align: left; background: #DADDD8; z-index: 0; }
.ui-slider { -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle { background: #8FB339; position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 15px; height: 15px; border-radius:5px; cursor:pointer; }
.ui-slider  .ui-state-hover, .ui-slider  .ui-state-active { background: #4B5842; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range { background: #C7D59F; position: absolute; z-index: 1; font-size: .7em; display: block; border: 0; background-position: 0 0; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range { -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(17,35,45,0.6) inset; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(17,35,45,0.6) inset; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(17,35,45,0.6) inset; }


.ui-slider-horizontal { height: 5px; width:100px; margin:5px auto; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle { top: -5px; margin-left: -5px; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range { top: 0; height: 100%; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min { left: 0; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max { right: 0; }

.slider-value{
  font-size:12px;
  float:right;
  margin-top:-16px;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

**JS/JQUERY :**

```
  $( function() {
    var div = $(".slider");
    $( ".slider" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( ".slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
            },
      min: div.data("slider-min"),
      max: div.data("slider-max"),
      value: div.data("svalue"),
})});

$( ".slider-value" ).html(  $(this).slider('value') );
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp9vH/14/) is this demo on **jsfiddle**

AND while I'm at it, I've got this other problem with the class/multiple sliders thing : when I want to **display the current value** of ONE slider, since it's a class it changes all the `.slider-value` spans. I do not know where to begin with this issue either.

Thank you for your time/help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you were on the right path, but you were throwing a few things in there that were redundant, probably from trying stuff and forgetting to remove them.

I've modified your code a little to make the function you have reusable. I've also nested the value field within the same div as the slider. This is to show you how easy jQuery makes it to find related elements, but you could relate them in other ways without having to nest them... Note that I didn't fix up the CSS, so it's a little messed up, but you can figure that out yourself...

The big change really though was the use of the **id** attribute, when using jQuery selectors, the 3 main types you can use (though there are others), are **CSS** class selectors `$(".slider")`, **element** selectors `$("div")`, and **id** selectors `$("#slider1")`.

Just try the following changes to the HTML and JavaScript:

JavaScript / jQuery:

```
var func = function(div) {
    var slide = $(div).slider({
      range: "min",
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $(div).find(".slider-value").html( ui.value );
            },
      min: parseInt(div.attr("slider-min")),
      max: parseInt(div.attr("slider-max")),
      value: parseInt(div.attr("svalue")),
    })
};

func($("#slider1"));
func($("#slider2"));
func($("#slider3"));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider" id="slider1" slider-min="15" slider-max="250" svalue="132"><span class="slider-value"></span>
</div>


<div class="slider" id="slider2" slider-min="30" slider-max="300" svalue="165"><span class="slider-value"></span></div>


<div class="slider" id="slider3" slider-min="100" slider-max="500" svalue="300"><span class="slider-value"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Richard! Your solution fixed the slider-value problem, but it looks like the min and max values still aren't changed (they're 0 and 100). Do you think you know why?

Comment: Also second question, sorry, I'm not sure what the slide var is for?

Comment: No problem. You can ignore the slide var, I was trying a different approach and left it in there by accident. I've updated the answer to correctly parse the values from the element attributes. I used jQuery's `.attr()` method, but this return the values as strings, which the slider object did not expect, so I then used the native JavaScript method `parseInt()` to convert the values to Number objects.

Comment: That works like a charm! Thanks a lot, I've removed the slide var from the code btw, hope you don't mind. If I can bother you one last time, do you think it's possible to display automatically without having to slide the value?

Comment: We would probably have to put it somewhere other than under the slide option of .slider()

Comment: :) I thought you might ask that... You can get it to do this with the code that's already there.  `slide: function( event, ui ) { ... }` is setting an event listener to do something when we slide the slider, inside we said for it to:  `$(div).find(".slider-value").html( ui.value ); `. So if we copy this bit of logic, and put it at the top of of function as a once off (i.e. instead of waiting for the slider to get triggered), then it's job done. Try sticking something like this at the start of the function: `$(div).find(".slider-value").html( parseInt(div.attr("svalue")) );`